# How to speed up MediaPlayer buffering on Android

Tags: android, video-streaming, android-mediaplayer, buffering

Hi I'm developing an application that uses Android MediaPlayer to play a background video usually of 30 seconds length.

With some videos that are less than 5-7MB the Player starts immediately, but when the video size goes over 10-15MB the video takes over 30 seconds before playing.

My question is: is there a way to **speed up** Android native **MediaPlayer Buffering** in order to play the first frame of the video **as soon as it is available** like YouTube?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know much about android native MediaPlayer but got similar problems using ExoPlayer and solve it by using LoadControl. If you don't find any solution with MediaPlayer maybe think about use ExoPlayer. Here is the link for discussion about DefaultLoadControl:

https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/2438

Comment: Thanks for your help, but can I integrate ExoPlayer like a view in the background??

Comment: I don't know but think that it should not be a big problem. Unfortunately my last experience with exoplayer was about year ago so I don't remember all things.

Comment: Thanks tried your answer with ExoPlayer defaultLoadControl and also very long video loads in seconds. Unfortunately StackOverflow does not allow me to vote your answer useful due to my reputation